Custom scrollbar with Dynamic Margin and Border radius
is it possible to somehow customize the scroll with dynamic margin (not for edges, e.g. - only right margin) and border-radius? If you try border-right instead of border, the radius on the right begins to be cut off. How can I fix this behavior?


.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.scroll-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 152px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px 0px #030D2D1A;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-container">
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 1</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 2</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 3</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>




Can you please add more details about what you are trying to achieve and the issues you are facing and what you have tried to solve them?

I want to be able to dynamically change the left and right scroll margins while saving the border radius.
In the current implementation, these margins are set using the "border" property. Everything goes well until you set the "border-right" or "border-left" property.In this case, the scroll rounding disappears on one side or the other. How to avoid this?

I think you are trying to set custom radius of right border of your scroll bar. However you can set right/left/top/left using border-radius property. What you need to do is:
border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0; //top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left

Border radius support four values (see above).
So If you change the right border radius, you need to set border-radius like above.


.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.scroll-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 152px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px 0px #030D2D1A;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 17px;
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-container">
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 1</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 2</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 3</button>
      <button class="scroll-container-button">Button 4</button>
  </div>
</div>




In your case the radius on the left is being cut off, this should not happen

Change the border-radius values as your requirements. Ex. border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px Instead of border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px for all side.

Maybe you are using border-right value bigger than border-radius value. If so, then radius will disappear. Border-right value should less than the border-radius value. Try it, you will find out what is happening with you.

try set
::-webkit-scrollbar {     width: 10px;     background: transparent; } ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {     border-left: 4px solid transparent;     background-clip: padding-box;     border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); }
Border right value less than border-radius, as you can see. But you have cropped scroll

*border-left value

I don't understand what are you saying. See the result image here Image Link. Take a Screenshot of output you're getting and comment here with image link as mine.

BTW If you set only border-left value then border radius will work only for border-left not for border-right. If you want to see radius of right border you have to set border-right value also.

It is necessary that the rounding is on both sides. In the screenshot, the rounding on the left is cropped

If it is necessary to make rounding on both sides, you need to set border-radius of both side. As you give snippet you set only border-left value, so border-radius will only work for left side border. Hope you understand.

The dynamic application of padding is set through the border property. Try setting border-radius to any value, and setting border-left. Your fillet on the left edge will be cut off.
See: https://imgur.com/a/upEVpqd
border-left: 10px; border-radius: 50px;

What type of border-radius you want. Clear me. See the images and tell me which want you want? Image-1, Image-2, Image-3, Image-4? See this: https://imgur.com/a/HtXyNvO
